# Disable Regional settings for NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextfield, regional-settings

I have a problem with NSTextField in Cocoa. Is there a way to remove regional settings from a NSTextField

I want the user to only enter values like so 0.6, 0.7 but if the user is not from US he is forced to enter like this 0,6,  0,7

So if the user is not US user if he enters 0.7 [textField floatValue] will return 0
and if the user is US and he enters 0,7 [textField floatValue] will return 0

Well lets say that is something i can accept but then i want to format the value and display it only with 3 decimals

this will work for US but will not work for non US even though value is a correct float (eg 0.3) 
    [textField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f",value]];

textfield is of type NSTextField

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`. In fact, using `NSNumberFormatter` allows you to:

- Configure the minimum and maximum number of digits after the decimal separator;
- Configure the string that’s used as the decimal separator in case you want to override the user’s locale;
- Configure the rounding behaviour, if that’s important;

amongst other features.

If your `NSTextField` is in a nib file, Interface Builder/Xcode 4 allows you to link the `formatter` outlet to an `NSNumberFormatter` instance. You can also do it programatically by sending `-setFormatter:` to the text field.